# iPad Safari missing bookmarks, favourites and reading list

Tags: ipad, safari

My iPad Safari bookmarks, favourites & reading list have disappeared. It won't let me bookmark or favourite any sites either. I've tried a hard restart, switching off iCloud & deleting cookies but to no avail. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Please stick to one question per, well, question (you can always ask the other topic in another question).

Comment: Regarding your bookmarks: Did you have iCloud bookmark syncing enabled before and also used it from another device? What happens if you now try to bookmark a site?

Answer (score -2):

Check your Restrictions.

If that doesn't work, back up your iPad and use iBackupBot to delete the Safari folder in app data.

after you delete Safari folder, Reset All Content And Settings(wipe)then activate and restore your iPad.

or just type safari in settings and clear history and website data, 
after that, you can sync you data from iCloud.

Comment: A rather drastic solution (and I'm not even sure it will solve the problem).

Comment: That's the last way to fix it, but it will work for sure.